# Problem with Resolve

Tags: equation-solving, logic

The question is: for which values of the parameter $a$ the equations $$4^{x+1}-3\ 2^{x+3}=2^{x+4}-64 $$ and $$(a+30) \left(-9^x\right)+3^{x+4}+27^x=a \left(81-10\ 3^{x+1}\right) $$ are equivalent? Here is my unsuccessful attempt with the `Resolve` command.

```
ForAll[x, x \[Element] Reals, Equivalent[4^(x + 1) - 3*2^(x + 3) == 2^(x + 4) - 64, 
 27^x - (a + 30)*9^x + 3^(x + 4) == a*(81 - 10*3^(x + 1))]];Resolve[%, a, Reals]
```

> !(*
>   SubscriptBox["[ForAll]", 
>   RowBox[{
>   RowBox[{"{", "x", "}"}], ",", 
>   RowBox[{"x", "[Element]", 
>   TemplateBox[{},
>   "Reals"]}]}]](((-3)\ 
>   *SuperscriptBox[(2), (3 + x)] + 
>   *SuperscriptBox[(4), (1 + x)] == (-64) + 
>   *SuperscriptBox[(2), (4 + x)] [Equivalent] 
>   *SuperscriptBox[(3), (4 + x)] + 
>   *SuperscriptBox[(27), (x)] - 
>   *SuperscriptBox[(9), (x)]\ ((30 + a)) == ((81 - 10\ 
>   *SuperscriptBox[(3), (1 + x)]))\ a)))

I found the following workaround. 
Comparing the outputs of

```
Solve[4^(x + 1) - 3*2^(x + 3) == 2^(x + 4) - 64, x, Reals]
```

> {{x->1},{x->3}}

and

```
Solve[27^x - (a + 30)*9^x + 3^(x + 4) == a*(81 - 10*3^(x + 1)), x, Reals]
```

> {{x->1},{x->3},{x->ConditionalExpression[Log[a]/Log[3],a>0]}}

, one draws the conclusion that the solution is $a\le 0$.

Does there exist another way to this end?

Comment: I unsuccessfully tried the SolveAlways command too.

Answer (score 2):

`ContourPlot`of both equations

```
ContourPlot[{4^(x + 1) - 3*2^(x + 3) == 2^(x + 4) - 64, 
27^x - (a + 30)*9^x + 3^(x + 4) == a*(81 - 10*3^(x + 1))}, {x, -4,4}, {a, -3, 3}, 
ContourStyle -> {{Thickness[.02], Blue}, Red},FrameLabel -> {x, a}]
```

[image]

shows the two equations are equivalent for `a<0`!

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this is rather a plausible reasoning than a proof. Also the case $a=0$ is unclear to me.

Comment: Surely it's not a proof. But it gives an idea that the both equations might be  equivalent for `x==1` and `x==3`.

Comment: In view of it +1 is mine.